# Snake Game Creating a multiple Squares as a body of snake

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from turtle import  Screen,Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600,600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("New Snake Game ")

turtle = Turtle(shape="square")
turtle.color("white")
# print(turtle)
x = 10
starting_position = []

for i in range(0,3):
    starting_position.append(turtle)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x=x,y=0)
    x += 20
print(starting_position)



screen.exitonclick()
```

I am creating a python Snake Game.while using for loop I came across this issue,
I want three squares to be created but squares are moving by 3 position. I dont know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `square` creation within the `for` loop so that it creates 3 different objects:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title('New Snake Game')

x = 10
for i in range(0, 3):
    turtle = Turtle(shape='square')
    turtle.color('white')
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x=x, y=0)
    x += 20

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image: Snake]